# Show Third Party Controls In Secured Site

Tags: security, ssl

We have a site which is running under SSL. We have to show controls in our site which uses some third party scripts. These controls are rendered in Internet Explorer8 after we accept a warning message displayed. Just for your information this is the warning message "To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors. Click for options". On clicking this security warning a menu opens, and we click "Display Blocked Content".

On click of this option a web page gets refreshed and shows a warning message :-

"Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered sceurely? This web page contanis content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could compromise the security of the entire web page."

On clicking yes button in this warning message third party control gets rendered in Internet Explorer8.

Based on above experience, we have following query :-

Can we simply show the third party control in our page, without showing any warning message in Internet Explorer?

Regards

Tarunjit Singh

Answer (score 0):

Only if the third party control is accessible via HTTPS (either on the third party domain, or if it is possible to include it under your domain).